# Creating a function called zip() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Part of an exercise I am to create a function called zip. It takes two arrays of equal length of elements and then separates them in two arrays with elements of equal indexes. I know there are other solutions using the map function but I am trying to figure out if there is another solution for this.  So far I have this:

```js
function zip(arr1, arr2) {
  let pairArr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if(arr1.length === arr2.length){
      let pairs = [arr1[i],arr2[i]];
      pairArr.push(pairs);
    } return pairArr;
  }
}
```

This returns just one array with the first indexes of two arrays.
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
returns [1, 1].  I need it to return [1, 1] [2, 2] [3, 3] [4, 4].
Thank you.

Comment: You should return after your loop is done, instead of inside the loop. An unconditional return inside a loop means the loop cannot iterate

Comment: You can't expect others think and write the code for you. You must think, try and debug.

Comment: Thank you Paul I didn't realize that.  I get that Jose but I have written this several ways and I just needed an outside perspective. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the return inside the loop. You should add it outside the loop. For example:

```js
function zip(arr1, arr2) {
       let pairArr = [];
             for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
                 if (arr1.length === arr2.length){
                     let pairs = [arr1[i],arr2[i]];
                     pairArr.push(pairs);
                    } 
             }
             return pairArr;
     }
     
     
     
console.log(zip([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4] ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone your input. I didn't realize that I had my return in the loop. I did solve it.  This is what I have for the zip function.

```
function zip(arr1, arr2) {
        let pairArr = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
                if (arr1.length === arr2.length){
                    pairArr[i] = [arr1[i],arr2[i]];


                }
            }return pairArr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better implementation of python-style zip in JavaScript, which can take an arbitrary number of arrays as arguments and returns a result as long as the shortest parameter.

```
const zip = (...arrays) => {
    const length = Math.min(...arrays.map(a => a.length));
    return [...Array(length).keys()].map(i => arrays.map(a => a[i]));
}
```